# Messagebox title from db value

Tags: messagebox

The below 1st command displays msg along with title as PPFC. I'm trying to fetch those info from db. The 2nd command shows that I'm able to get the msg from db but I couldn't set title from db column. Instead of "PPFC" I'm tring to put resulterr[2].SCREEN_NM.ToString() so that it fetches and displays in title.

1) MessageBox.Show("PLEASE SELECT A VALUE FROM DIVISION DROPDOWN","PPFC");

2) MessageBox.Show(resulterr[2].ERROR_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE.ToString() + ", " + resulterr[2].SCREEN_NM.ToString(), "PPFC", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

Comment: What language is this? C#?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the overloaded method

```
MessageBox.Show(String,String);
```

can be used to specify the caption in addition to the actual message. If more details of the message box have to be specified, [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used.